# How to make GNU screen recognize UTF-8 characters

Tags: bash, macos, unicode, gnu-screen

I like to have different prompts in bash to recognize quickly on which machine I am currently working when I use `ssh`. I found that the default bash terminal in OSX Yosemite accepts a wide range of unicode characters, so I set up these `PS1`:

*Mac PS1*

```
PS1=$'\n\n\xf0\x9f\x98\x88'"  \t – \[\033[01m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\W > "
```

*Raspberry π PS1*

```
PS1=$'\n\n\xf0\x9f\x98\xBA'"  \t – \[\033[01m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\W > "
```

Unfortunately, [GNU screen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screen.1.html) does not understand UTF-8 characters:

- F0 9F 98 BA  http://unicode-table.com/fr/1F63A/
- F0 9F 98 88   http://unicode-table.com/fr/1F608/

even when run in UTF-8 mode with `screen -U`

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

1) In GNU screen type CTRL+A, then type this screen directive:

**:utf8 on**

(Not sure why -U does not already do it.)

2) Also check your locale by typing "**locale -a**" in a shell.

This should have UTF-8 near the top of the output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Svetlana.

The `utf-8` command is not a Bash command and I also tried to type `CTRL-A :utf-8 on <return>` in gnu-screen, but it doesn’t work , so where should I use this command?

On my Raspberry Pi, the `locale -a` command returns `C`, `C.UTF-8`, `en_GB.utf8`, `POSIX`.

How can I set UTF-8 at the top?

Comment: @nico Ctrl+a :utf8 on<return> [source](https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment)

Comment: screen command `:utf8 on on` is required to change also the display's encoding.